# Display Unique Values from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm reporting my question to be a little more succinct. (deleted other)

I have a time reporting system I have built, and I am trying to create an adherence type report.

Esentially I'm trying to do the following:

1. Gather all unique names ($fn, $ln) in my database, based on a where clause and the fields practice=ccv & year=2016 (for example)
2. Then I also want to gather up another list of names ($fn, $ln), based on practice=ccv & year=2016 and additional where clause week=8
3. This will give me 2 DISTINCT lists that I can compare, and the difference will be the Outstanding timecards for week 8.

From there, I need to display all the names for submitted (from #3 above) and also the list of outstanding (by comparing the #1 and #2 above)

Thus far, I can get the list of names. However, I then need to display them with additional data from the database for each person (Region, Timestamp, etc ..)

Desired Output would be something like this:

**Submitted**
**EMEA**
John J
Wally R
**North America**
Davis D
Bob C
John Y

**Outstanding**
**EMEA**
Kyle D
**North America**
Cory T
Hugh R
John J
**LATAM**
etc ....

Thus far, here is what I have .. I'm sure I'm going about this the wrong way.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx!","xxx");                  

//Get distinct names from practice
if ($con) {
$SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT fn,ln FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes' ORDER BY region,fn,ln";   
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,$SQL);

if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 

while ( $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
$name[] = trim($db_field['fn']. " " .$db_field['ln']);
}


//Get distinct names for current week practice
if ($con) {
$SQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT fn,ln FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND week_num='$week' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes' ORDER BY region,fn,ln"; 
}

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$SQL2);

if (!$result2) die('Couldn\'t fetch records Again'); 

while ( $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2) ) {

$name2[] = trim($db_field['fn']. " " .$db_field['ln']);
}

//$SQL3 = "SELECT fn,ln,week_start_date,region FROM $table WHERE fn IN ( '".implode("', '", $differences)."' )");

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<TABLE><TR><TD>
<B>All Names</B><BR>
<?php
foreach ( $name as $item ) {
    echo $item . "<br/>";
}
?>
</TD>
<TD>
<B>Names for Week 8</B><BR>
<?php
foreach ( $name2 as $item2 ) {
    echo $item2 . "<br/>";
}
?>
</TD>
<TD>
<B>Outstanding</B><BR>
<?php
$results = array_diff($name, $name2);

foreach($results as $val) {
    echo $val ." - ".$val2."<BR>";          
}
?>

</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should solve this at MySQL level.

```
// All names with all data
$SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT *, CONCAT(fn,' ',ln) AS `name` FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes' ORDER BY region,fn,ln";

// Names for specific week with all data
$SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT *, CONCAT(fn,' ',ln) AS `name` FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND week_num='$week' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes' ORDER BY region,fn,ln";

// Outstanding rows with all data
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT *, CONCAT(fn,' ',ln) AS `name` FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes') AS `subquery` WHERE `name` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(fn,' ',ln) AS `name` FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND week_num='$week' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes') ORDER BY region,fn,ln";
```

This way you won't need to sort and process data at PHP-level. Can't test this since I don't have the database environment but it should work, may require some small changes.

Comment: This is what I was looking for ... I knew the sql level was a better spot to work this out. I'll do some testing and report back ! Thanks very much.

Comment: struggling with the third query. First 2 work fine if I remove " , * " ....  $SQL3 = "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(fn,' ',ln) AS 'name', * FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes' AND 'name' NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(fn,' ',ln) AS 'name' FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND week_num='$week' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes') AS subquery ORDER BY region,fn,ln";

Comment: throws the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM rtu_prem_ww WHERE year='2016' AND practice='ccv' AND archived!='yes' AND ' at line 1

Comment: if I remove " , * " and replace it with " , region " it moves on but then I get: server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS subquery ORDER BY region,fn,ln' at line 1

Comment: Try my edited queries above. Think I found the errors.

Comment: still getting the following on the 3rd one: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM rtu_prem_ww WHERE year='2016' AND practice='ccv' AND archived!='yes' AND ' at line 1 ... other 2 I have working fine

Comment: When I remove " , * " and put " , region " it gets by it .. then this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS 'subquery' ORDER BY region,fn,ln' at line 1

Comment: Server version: 5.5.48-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Great, do this instead: $SQL3 = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT(fn,' ',ln) AS name, region, fn, ln FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes' GROUP BY name) AS subquery WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(fn,' ',ln) AS name FROM $table WHERE year='$year' AND week_num='$week' AND practice='$practice' AND archived!='yes') ORDER BY region,fn,ln";